# D&D Adventure game system, additional adventures

Tags: dnd-adventure-system

Where can I obtain additional story adventures for the various D&D adventure game systems?

In all the manuals it states to check the wizards of the coast site for them, but there are none on the site and even a wizard's support rep confirmed that there are none hosted on the site. Rather frustrating.

Does anyone know where I can get some? I'm looking to expand upon the fun for my gaming group but have not found the time to sit down and create my own.

Comment: You might want to check on boardgamegeek.

Comment: Boardgamegeek has links to official WoTC adventures, but they are all dead and they don't seem to be accessible from the wayback machine since they are PDFs.  It does have some unofficial ones though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This BGG geeklist](https://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/59113/item/1424794#item1424794) seems to have links to a bunch of user generated content.  It also has links to the official WoTC adventures, but they seem to be permanently removed at this point, so the only way to get them would be from someone that already has the PDFs.